# RESTeasy and X-HTTP-Method-Override

Tags: java, resteasy

Are there any way that support the X-HTTP-Method-Override request header
(automatically/transparently) in RESTeasy?

This would
make it much easier to support clients that cannot send PUT/DELETE requests.

Yes, overriding POST is less than ideal but I think the Google convention of
using X-HTTP-Method-Override is a reasonable/convenient work-around.

If RESTeasy
could dispatch POST requests with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header
automatically it would be a big time saver. I think Jersey just added something
like this via a filtering approach, but I'd prefer to stick with RESTeasy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In RESTeasy processing headers are supported by using interceptors, which are described in the [Reference Guide](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html-single/RESTEasy_Reference_Guide/index.html#Interceptors).

What you want, is probably a PreProcessInterceptor which intercepts the call, looks for the header and changes the method string/redirects as necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Recently I had the same problem and the best solution I've found is:

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class OverrideHttpMethodFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
        throws IOException {        
    String receivedMethod = requestContext.getMethod();
    String methodFromHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString("X-HTTP-Method-Override");
    if (methodFromHeader != null && !methodFromHeader.equals(receivedMethod)) {
        requestContext.setMethod(methodFromHeader);
    }
  }
}
```